# Is it possible to handle Get-AzureManagedCache exception in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, exception, azure, redis

I am writing a script to setup a Redis cache in Azure.  Prior to setting up a new cache, I want to check for its existence by running this:

```
    $cache = Get-AzureManagedCache -Name $cacheName
```

If the cache doesn't exist, it outputs this "exception":

*Get-AzureManagedCache : Cache Service 'PrototypeFOO' was not found
At C:\builds\repos-scm\branches\2.6\2.6.0\scm\AzureDeploymentSandbox\Scripts\Create-RedisCache.ps1:39 char:15
+         $cache = Get-AzureManagedCache -Name $cacheName
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureManagedCache], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ManagedCache.GetAzureManagedCache*

So I wrap it in a try/catch block like this:

```
try
{
    $cache = Get-AzureManagedCache -Name $cacheName 
}
catch 
{
    Write-Host "Catching the exception"
}
```

And when I run it, it skips right over the catch statement and keeps on processing.  I am able to append "-EA SilentlyContinue" to the first line to suppress the message, but I am concerned that will suppress legit errors as well, so I would like to avoid that.  Any thoughts on how to handle this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the try/catch block, but add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the Azure call.

Alternatively, you can set `$ErrorActionPreference='Stop';` at the top of your script, which will automatically make all Errors act like they do in .NET.